# Wait until form is finished loading

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there some sort of boolean that I can use to check whether the instance of a form is loaded, or otherwise wait until the form is loaded?

for example:

```
While(form_loaded == false) {
  Try {
    //do something
  }
  catch {
  }//do try catch so code won't barf
}
```

I keep getting the following exception:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
>
> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
>
> Additional information: `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.

This is what I am worrying about.

Additionally if a more detailed explanation is needed I can try to post some code and/or some more output debugging information.

Comment: Your code will not compile against any C# compiler (I know it's example/pseudo-code, but that's beside the point.)

Comment: Just use `Form_Shown`

Comment: You need to do this the other way around.  Don't start the thread until the form's Load event fires.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

try to use  the shown event something  like this

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Shown += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Shown);
    }

    private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

hope this  help

Comment: In general, the event should be subscribed to/delegated in the designer.

Answer (score 10):

The first event that is triggered after form is fully loaded is the `Shown` event. use it...

---

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86faxx0d.aspx) the event sequence is :

**When application starts:**

- Control.HandleCreated
- Control.BindingContextChanged
- Form.Load
- Control.VisibleChanged
- Form.Activated
- Form.Shown

**When an application closes:**

- Form.Closing
- Form.FormClosing
- Form.Closed
- Form.FormClosed
- Form.Deactivate

And as @Henk Holterman stated in his answer, don't use busy waiting in an event driven form...

Answer (score 6):

You have a `Loaded` and a `Shown` event to pick from.

Windows is event driven so never wait for something in a loop.